# Active Directory Power Shell. Deleting Old User Accounts

Tags: powershell

Currently trying to make a script command within powershell for active directory. Everything I am finding online is giving errors when I try running it. "Exception calling "FindAll" with "0" argument(s): "A referral was returned from the server.""

Comment: please show your code that generated those errors. i have not seen any _functional_ mind reading modules yet ... [*grin*]

Comment: $datetime =  ((get-date).adddays($lastlogon)).ToFileTime() 
$Stamp = "{0:yyyyMMddHHmmss}.0Z" -f (get-date).adddays($lastlogon) 
import-module activedirectory 
$objDomain=New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry($adPath) 
$ObjSearch=New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher($ObjDomain) 
$ObjSearch.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(|(lastlogontimestamp<="+$datetime+")(&(whenCreated<="+$Stamp+")(!lastlogontimestamp=*))))" 
$allSearchResult = $ObjSearch.FindAll() 
$allSearchResult.Count 
foreach ($objSearchResult in $allSearchResult)

Comment: [1] you should put the code in your original post. [*grin*] ///// [2] WHY are you using `System.DirectoryServices.<whatever>` when you have loaded the active directory module? ///// [3] your code ends after the `foreach` block - where is the remainder of the code? ///// [4] where does `$lastlogon` come from? or `$adPath`?

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking for help, it would be a question of decorum to take the time to formulate a clear question. For example, you do not say what you mean by "old user accounts" and you do not spend the time to offer a pretty printed code in your question??

This PowerShell Command lists the Last logon time and the Days since the last logon time.
**If the user never logged in, then $null is returned.**

```
Get-ADUser -Filter { Enabled -Eq $True } -Properties SamAccountName, DisplayName, LastLogonTimestamp | Select-Object -Property SamAccountName, DisplayName, 
    @{ Name='LastLogonDate'; Expression={ If ($_.'LastLogonTimestamp' -eq $null) { $null } Else { [datetime]::FromFileTime($_.'LastLogonTimestamp') }}},
    @{ Name='LastLogonDays'; Expression={ If ($_.'LastLogonTimestamp' -eq $null) { $null } Else { (([datetime]::FromFileTime($_.'LastLogonTimestamp'))-(Get-Date)).Days }}}


SamAccountName DisplayName      LastLogonDate       LastLogonDays
-------------- -----------      -------------       -------------
User1          Hans Muster      06.10.2014 10:32:58         -1483
User2          Fritz Kunz
```